# phpmyadmin не отображается результат select

Tags: phpmyadmin

делаю два запроса в одной вкладке SQL, не получается отобразить результат запроса `select`:

```
SET @sdate := "2017-09-01"; 
(
  SELECT a.userId
      , b.dekan_fam_init AS fullname
      , ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a
     , `catalogDekan` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id 
      AND a.dateIns > @sdate 
      AND (a.userRole = "ROLE_DEKAN" 
          OR a.userRole = "ROLE_METHODIST" 
          OR a.userRole = "ROLE_STUDY_DEP_BOSS" 
          OR a.userRole = "ROLE_VICERECTOR" 
          OR a.userRole = "ROLE_ADMIN"
       )
   GROUP BY a.userId
 ) 
 UNION (
   SELECT a.userId
        , b.kaf_shufr AS fullname
        , ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
   FROM `catalogs_log` a
      , `catalogDepartOper` b 
   WHERE a.userId = b.id 
        AND a.userRole = "ROLE_DEP_OPER" 
        AND a.dateIns > @sdate 
   GROUP BY a.userId
)
UNION (
   SELECT a.userId
        , b.chief_fam_init AS fullname
        , ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
   FROM `catalogs_log` a
      , `catalogDepartChief` b 
   WHERE a.userId = b.id 
       AND a.userRole = "ROLE_ZAVKAF" 
       AND a.dateIns > @sdate 
   GROUP BY a.userId
)
ORDER BY cou DESC;
```

Получаю вот что:

```
SET @sdate := "2017-09-01";
# MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). 

(SELECT a.userId, b.dekan_fam_init AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDekan` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.dateIns > @sdate 
    AND (a.userRole = "ROLE_DEKAN" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_METHODIST" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_STUDY_DEP_BOSS" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_VICERECTOR" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_ADMIN") 
  GROUP BY a.userId) 
UNION (SELECT a.userId, b.kaf_shufr AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDepartOper` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.userRole = "ROLE_DEP_OPER" AND a.dateIns > @sdate GROUP BY a.userId) 
UNION (SELECT a.userId, b.chief_fam_init AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDepartChief` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.userRole = "ROLE_ZAVKAF" AND a.dateIns > @sdate GROUP BY a.userId) 
ORDER BY cou DESC;
#  Строк: 11
```

Вопрос: как отобразить содержимое полученных 11 строк ?

Понятно, что можно написать

```
SET @sdate := "2017-09-01"; 
create table result as 
(SELECT a.userId, b.dekan_fam_init AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDekan` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.dateIns > @sdate AND (a.userRole = "ROLE_DEKAN" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_METHODIST" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_STUDY_DEP_BOSS" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_VICERECTOR" OR a.userRole = "ROLE_ADMIN") GROUP BY a.userId) 
UNION (SELECT a.userId, b.kaf_shufr AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDepartOper` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.userRole = "ROLE_DEP_OPER" AND a.dateIns > @sdate GROUP BY a.userId) 
UNION (SELECT a.userId, b.chief_fam_init AS fullname, ceil(count(*)/2) AS cou 
  FROM `catalogs_log` a, `catalogDepartChief` b 
  WHERE a.userId = b.id AND a.userRole = "ROLE_ZAVKAF" AND a.dateIns > @sdate GROUP BY a.userId) 
ORDER BY cou DESC;
```

и потом уже посмотреть содержимое result.

Есть ли способ отобразить результат сразу, без create table?

Comment: а вы зачем там скобки ставите в юнионах? и вы вообще в курсе оператора `IN` ?

Comment: пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, читать невозможно. А еще лучше, сократите его до минимально воспроизводимого примера. И лучше укажите сразу чем именно отличаются работающий корректно и не корректно примеры. а то какое-то "найдите два отличия"...

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что проблема в том, что phpmyadmin не отображает эти 11 строк результата?

Comment: vp_arth, проблема именно в этом

Comment: и так со всеми, содержащими более одного SQL-запроса

Comment: Ну так, если проблема не в запросе, почему бы не привести минимальный пример вместо этих портянок?

Comment: А зачем пользоваться именно phpmyadmin ? стандартный клиент MySQL например отлично показывает результат. В дальнейшем вы же наверняка будете выполнять этот запрос из своего приложения, а не из phpmyadmin и проблем опять же не будет. Но если очень хочется, уберите SET и перенесите установку переменной в самую первую часть запроса, думаю в первом where часть `AND a.dateIns > (@sdate:="2017-09-01")` сделает то что нужно.

Comment: MIke, спасибо за помощь !
Стандартный клиент мне недоступен,

Comment: В приложение запрос мне вставлять нет необходимости, перенос установки переменной в тело запроса - оптимальное решение.